# Axios response data is empty, but the component rendered the response data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

```
const categoryLoadList = async ({
  category,
}: CategoryLoadListRequestType): Promise<CategoryType[]> =>
  await axios
    .get<CategoryType[]>(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/category${
        category !== "" ? "/search" : ""
      }`,
      {
        params: {
          category: category !== "" ? category : undefined,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    });
```

```
function useCategory(id: string = "") {
  return useQuery("categoryQuery", () => categoryLoadList({ category: id }), {
    cacheTime: 20000, //86400000,
    staleTime: 20000, //3600000,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    retry: 0,
  });
}
```

When I log response data,
"(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]" printed and the length is 0...
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/921423896270491668/1083620608585252914/console.log.png

But the thing is that the item lists component that uses this response data has items in it!

1. I used Asnyc / Await.
2. it only happens on first render.
3. category parameter in function is not used here. (category = "")
4. in the Network tab (DevTools), I see that response data is not empty. (I also tried on Postman, and the response data is not empty there either.)

What I want is that I get response data properly, not just an empty array...

Comment: "_When I log response data, "(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]" printed_" - the length is clearly three and the data shows everywhere. Your post is confusing, can you clarify please?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Okay! I uploaded an image of what is printed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I don't know exactly when but) sometimes, when you log a promise, the console log will update as soon as the promise is resolved. The logging might be related to that (maybe logging is done and length is 0, but as promise is resolved, the array reference gets updated, but not the length as it's passed by value).

Using async/await and `.then()` chaining seems very weird, you should stick to one or the other I think. Maybe that part is causing the initial render to get a bit weird.